# Is cudaEventRecord affected by the identity of the current device?

Tags: cuda, multi-gpu, cuda-events

cudaEventRecord [takes an event ID and a stream ID as parameters](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__EVENT.html#group__CUDART__EVENT_1gf4fcb74343aa689f4159791967868446). The Runtime API reference does not say whether the stream is required to be associated with the current device - and I can't test whether that's the case since I only have one GPU at most on any system I have access to right now.

Assuming that it must be a stream on the current device:

- what happens if it gets a stream on another device?

Assuming that it can be a stream on any device:

- What happens when it gets the (current device's) default stream's ID? After all, all devices' default streams have the same (null) ID?
- Is there any difference in behavior based on whether the stream's device is current or not?

Comment: some possibly relevant information is [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-selection)

Comment: @RobertCrovella: That strongly implies the answer to my initial question is "no". See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Combining the information from @Talonmies' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40671020/1593077) and the [Stream and Event Behavior section](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-selection) of the [CUDA C Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/) which @RobertCrovella linked to in his comment.</sub>

> Must the stream be associated with the current device?

**No**, it can be any device. However, event recording does require that the stream and the event be associated with the same device.

> Is there any difference in behavior based on whether the stream's device is current or not?

**Typically, no, but...**

> What happens when it gets the (current device's) default stream's ID?

**... the Default stream is an exception to that rule.** Since (each device's own) default stream has the same ID, passing the null ID to `cudaEventRecord` means that it *will* check what device is currently set to determine which stream to record the event on (and this needs to be the same device the event is associated with).